# TreeNode stack Depth First Search

Tags: c#

I saw this topic: Depth First Search without stack [closed]. I have a question related to this function. I want to use stack.
As I am C# beginner and a wondering if someone can explain me in detail 1) what the following program goal and 2) what the expected output.

```
void Foo(TreeNode root)
{
    Stack nodes = new Stack();
    nodes.Push(root);

    while (nodes.Count > 0)
    {
        TreeNode node = (TreeNode) nodes.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine(node.Text);
        for (int i = node.Nodes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            nodes.Push(node.Nodes[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The goal is to get the expected output, so that's just 1 question.

Comment: I would think the best way to find out would be to create different trees and run them through the code to find out.  Take a look at the pre-order image [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
        Foo(new TreeNode()
        {
            Text = "test",
            Nodes = new List<TreeNode>()
            {

                new TreeNode(){Text = "a"},
                new TreeNode(){
                    Text = "b",
                    Nodes = new List<TreeNode>()
                    {

                        new TreeNode(){Text = "c"},
                        new TreeNode(){Text = "d"},
                    }
                },
            }
        } );
```

Result:

```
test
a
b
c
d
```

Basically on each trip in the loop gets the first item in the stack and adds to the stack its children (if any). Then it re-fetches the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

> I am C# beginner and a wondering if someone can explain me in detail 1) what the following program goal and 2) what the expected output.

I think it is important to understand the overall concept first, not the implementation in a particular programming language. So, in short: the goal of Depth First Search is to traverse a Tree or a Graph "in depth", checking some condition that is applicable to nodes (quite frequently the goal is to find the node with particular key, for example). This way of traversing is implemented by the stack data structure.